# One-ended finitely presented subgroups of hyperbolic groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

In *Hyperbolic groups* (page 82), Gromov claims that, by a standard application of Thurston's method of *geodesic (hyperbolic) simplices*, it can be prove that a hyperbolic group contains finitely many pairwise non conjugate subgroups isomorphic to a fixed one-ended finitely presented group.

I took a look on the usual references dealing with hyperbolic groups, but I didn't find any details. Do you know references about this result and/or Thurston's method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a proof of this theorem due to Thomas Delzant:

T. Delzant, L’image d’un groupe dans un groupe hyperbolique, Comment. Math. Helv.
70 (1995), no. 2, 267–284.

There is also a version for relatively hyperbolic groups du to Francois Dahmani:

Accidental Parabolics and Relatively Hyperbolic Groups, Israel Journal of Mathematics, Volume 153, Issue 1, pp 93–127

Comment: There is also a different argument using the Rips machine and the shortening argument that shows that there are only finitely many monomorphisms (up to precomposition with an automorphism) from a finitely generated one-ended group to a fixed hyperbolic group. In the torsion-free case I think you can find it in the paper "Structure and rigidity ... " by Rips and Sela. The case with torsion needs a version of the Rips machine due to Guirardel.

Comment: PS: "Structure and rigidity ... " needs finitely presented, but the argument goes through using the version of the Rips machine due to Sela in "Acylindrical accessibilty" which was then generalized (and fixed) by Guirardel.